# UNKNOWN State for moving state

Tags: android, fleetboard

My app does always get UNKNOWN as restriction/moving state when I use the vehicle API to read the state from the Truck even the Truck is moving. What can I do to get the correct values and what does the state Unknown mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UNKNOWN state indicates, that the platform is not able to determine the restrictionstate. This typically means, that no information can be acquired about the vehicle’s movementstate. This can be the case if there is no (logical) connection to the vehicle.